# Approximating a projection in a tensor product of C$^{*}$-algebras in a certain way

Tags: operator-theory, tensor-products, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be two C$^{*}$-algebras (assume $B=\mathcal{O}_{2}\otimes\mathcal{K}$ if it helps) and suppose we have a non-zero projection $p\in A\otimes B$. (We can assume $A$ is nuclear, so that there is only one possible tensor product.)

Does there exist a choice of elements $a_{1},\ldots,a_{n}\in A$ and $b_{1},\ldots,b_{n}\in B$ such that:

1. $\left\|\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\otimes
       b_{i}\right)-p\right\|<\frac{1}{2}$;
2. If $\pi$ is a non-zero irreducible representation of $A$ and $(\pi\otimes\operatorname{id})(p)=0$, then $\pi\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{i}|\right)=0$?

All I can deduce is that for a given choice of $a_{i}$'s and $b_{i}$'s, and and irreducible representation $\pi$ of $A$, we have
$$
\left\|\sum_{i=1}^{n}\pi(a_{i})\otimes b_{i}\right\|=\left\|(\pi\otimes \operatorname{id})\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\otimes b_{i}\right)-p\right)\right\|\leq \left\|\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\otimes b_{i}\right)-p\right\|<\frac{1}{2},
$$
provided that $(\pi\otimes\operatorname{id})(p)=0$.

Comment: This question has been answered in the affirmative here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357369/approximating-a-projection-by-a-sum-of-elementary-tensors-with-a-certain-propert